# A less verbose way to update QT widgets from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm writing a QT application that receives messages on other threads that I need to update from another thread. I'm using connections and slots, but it's becoming unimaginably verbose to create a signal and connect it for every function I want to call on every widget. Is there a better way?

here is an example:

```
class StateWidget : public QWidget, public AbstractTab {
 Q_OBJECT

  \\ ...

 signals:

  void SetLeftVelocity(QString str);
  void SetRightVelocity(QString str);
  void SetLeftCurrent(QString str);
  void SetRightCurrent(QString str);

  \\ there are ~30 more of these lines. very annoying!
  \\ ...
}
```

The in my constructor I need all of the connects...

```
  connect(this, SIGNAL(SetLeftVelocity(QString)), ui_->left_velocity_edit,
          SLOT(setText(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(SetRightVelocity(QString)), ui_->right_velocity_edit,
          SLOT(setText(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(SetLeftCurrent(QString)), ui_->left_current_edit,
          SLOT(setText(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(SetRightCurrent(QString)), ui_->right_current_edit,
          SLOT(setText(QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
  connect(this, SIGNAL(SetLeftAcceleration(QString)), ui_->left_acceleration_edit,
  \\ so many more...
```

Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Do your non-GUI threads really need to have explicit knowledge about every single one of your GUI widgets?  You might want to abstract things a bit more, so that your GUI isn't tied so closely to your non-GUI code.  For example, you could have the non-GUI threads emit a variableChanged(QString varName, QVariant varValue) signal only, and connect that to a single slot in the GUI thread that calls the right method on the right widget based on (varName).

Answer (score 0):

If signals and slots belong to the same class (what in your example seems to be the case), then it's all encapsulated, so I dont think there is a problem here.

But if you are mixing signals and slots from different classes I would rather go for some kind of [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design instead of connecting all signals/slots within single constructor.